# How to access item metadata outside <Target> node in MsBuild?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget, msvcrt

I'm trying to make a `.targets` file for my NuGet package, which will link to a proper `.lib` file depending on the C++ runtime library of a project. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4725538/261217) recommends to use `%(ClCompile.RuntimeLibrary)` metadata for this. But it seems like metadata cannot be accessed outside the `<Target>` node! And library dependencies are added in `<ItemDefinitionGroup>` node just under the root `<Project>` node.

Here is the SSCCE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="main.cpp">
      <RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreadedDebugDLL</RuntimeLibrary>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <RuntimeLibrary>%(ClCompile.RuntimeLibrary)</RuntimeLibrary>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="Build">
    <Message Text="Property = $(RuntimeLibrary)" Importance="high" />
    <Message Text="Metadata = %(ClCompile.RuntimeLibrary)" Importance="high" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Running it with MsBuild yields:

```
Property = %(ClCompile.RuntimeLibrary)
Metadata = MultiThreadedDebugDLL
```

The same statement `%(ClCompile.RuntimeLibrary)` is expanded to the value when used inside `<Target>` node, but not when used in `<PropertyGroup>` node outside `<Target>` node.

So how can I access runtime library metadata value to add reference the proper library?

**Update:** The suggested, but not satisfying fix is to define `RuntimeLibrary` like the following:

```
<RuntimeLibrary>@(ClCompile->'%(RuntimeLibrary)')</RuntimeLibrary>
```

Output of the initial script is proper in this case, but *my task is still not solved*, since I want to use this property in a condition. So if I add the following:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(RuntimeLibrary)'=='MultiThreadedDebugDLL'">
  <TestProp>defined</TestProp>
</PropertyGroup>
...
<Message Text="TestProp = $(TestProp)" Importance="high" />
```

`TestProp` is undefined. How do I make this work for conditions?

Comment: re: your edit: that will work if you put that PropertyGroup in the Target iteself - or if you use `Condition="'@(ClCompile->'%(RuntimeLibrary)')'`. I'm not 100% sure but I think the way you wrote it won't work due to the eveluation order msbuild uses.

Comment: @stijn I cannot put this property in a `<Target>`, since I need to use it in a condition for `<ItemDefinitionGroup>`, which cannot be placed in a `<Target>` :(

Comment: Well then the condition with `@` seems the only solution?

Comment: @stijn Yes, but it is not working too. Besides, `@(ClCompile->'%(RuntimeLibrary)')` is expanded to a string like `MultiThreadedDebugDLL;MultiThreadedDebugDLL;MultiThreadedDebugDLL` in case there are several files in a project (which is almost always true), and requires split before usage. Not sure whether it is possible to make this split in the condition itself.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following instead:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <RuntimeLibrary>@(ClCompile->'%(RuntimeLibrary)')</RuntimeLibrary>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Using the @ symbol allows you to reference item lists.

There is also [an example on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149705/in-msbuild-why-isnt-item-metadata-within-a-property-being-resolved).

Comment: Sorry, this fix is not suitable for me. See the updated question.

Comment: Helped me to conditionally call a Target based on presence of Items resolved from an Include with a wildcard.